# RaiseError(...) is not cancelling out of my current triggered send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

I have a triggered send by way of a Transactional API email (Journey Builder > Create Transactional Email). The email's body looks like:

```
%%[ 
if indexOf([Template Body], "You have an unsubmitted application for") > 0 then 
  RaiseError("Unsubmitted Application Email detected, stopping send"); 
endif 

if [Send Mail] == 0 and [Send SMS] == 1 then 
  set @mobileNumber = [Recipient Phone Number] 
  set @messageText = [Template Body] 
  
  set @regex = "\<.*?\>"
  set @outputMessageText = RegExMatch(@regex, @messageText, 0)
  
  set @url = Concat('https://cloud.xxx.domain.com/temp?mobileNumber=',@mobileNumber,'&message=',@outputMessageText) 
  set @result = HTTPGet(@url) 
  RaiseError("Send Mail attribute in TSDE is FALSE, stopping email send")
endif 
if [Send Mail] == 0 and [Send SMS] == 0 then
  RaiseError("Send Mail attribute in TSDE is FALSE, along with Send SMS. Stopping email send")
endif
]%%
```

However when I execute this triggered send and pass False for Send Mail and True for Send SMS, I still receive the email.  However when I "Preview and Test" the email with that same triggered send data extension record, the preview will fail to generate due to the RaiseError(...).  What might be going on???

Answer (score 1):

The problem is evidently due to when you make a change to the email in Content Builder, the changes aren't reflected on the Transactional Message (much like needing to republish a triggered send definition).  So, the solution was to edit the email within the Journey and saving.  The Journey was never using the most recent email version.